# How to run this code faster?

Tags: java, performance

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ristsumma {
static long numberFromFile;
static long sum1, sum2;
static long number, number2;
static long variable, variable2;
static long counter;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ristsis.txt"));
        numberFromFile = Long.parseLong(br.readLine()); 

        br.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    variable=numberFromFile;
    ArrayList<Long> numbers = new ArrayList<Long>();

    while (variable > 0){
        number = variable %10;
        variable/=10;
        numbers.add(number);
    }

    for (int i=0; i< numbers.size(); i++) {
        sum1 += numbers.get(i);
    }

    ArrayList<Long> numbers2 = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for(long s=1; s<numberFromFile; s++){
        variable2=s;
        number2=0;
        sum2=0;

        while (variable2 > 0){
            number2 = variable2 %10;
            variable2/=10;  
            numbers2.add(number2);
        }

        for (int i=0; i< numbers2.size(); i++) {
            sum2 += numbers2.get(i);
        }

        if(sum1==sum2){
        counter+=1; 
        }

        numbers2.clear();
    }       
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("ristval.txt", "UTF-8");
pw.println(counter);
pw.close();

}
}
```

So I have this code. It takes a number from a file, adds all numbers separately from that number and adds them together (for example the number is 123 then it gives 1+2+3=6). In the second half it looks out all numbers from 1 to that number in the file and counts how many different numbers give the same answer. If the number is 123, the sum is 6 and the answer that the code writes is 9 (because 6, 15, 24, 33, 42, 51, 60, 105, 114 also give the same answer). The code works, but my problem is that when the number from a file is for example 2 222 222 222, then it takes almost half an hour to get the answer. How can I make this run faster?

Comment: @lordkain I doubt the same algorithm will run faster in a different programming language =\...

Comment: What if the sum is greater than 9? E.g. does `999` give you `27` or `9`?

Comment: Please consider searching for a generic answer to 'how to make my code run faster'.  That will almost always be faster :) than asking on a 'forum'.

Comment: @lordkain [insert lengthy which is best language argument]

Comment: You probably spend a lot of excess time resizing the ArrayList. Collections are for convenience, not speed.

Comment: How do you know this code can be made to run faster? Perhaps it's just a time-consuming calculation.

Comment: Botom line: Better coding, threading and last but not least clever algorithms make things get faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Remove unnecessary creation of lists

You are unnecessarily creating lists

```
ArrayList<Long> numbers = new ArrayList<Long>();

while (variable > 0){
    number = variable %10;
    variable/=10;
    numbers.add(number);
}

for (int i=0; i< numbers.size(); i++) {
    sum1 += numbers.get(i);
}
```

Here you create an arraylist, just to temporaily hold Longs, you can eliminate the entire list

```
while (variable > 0){
    number = variable %10;
    variable/=10;
    sum1 += number
}
```

The same for the other arraylist numbers2

### Presize arralists

We have already eliminated the arraylists but if we hadn't we could improve speed by presizing the arrays

```
ArrayList<Long> numbers = new ArrayList<Long>(someGuessAsToSize);
```

It isn't nessissary that your guess be correct, the arraylist will still auto resize, but if the guess is approximately correct you will speed up the code as the arraylist will not have to periodically resize.

### General style

You are holding lots of (what should be) method variables as fields

```
static long numberFromFile;
static long sum1, sum2;
static long number, number2;
static long variable, variable2;
static long counter;
```

This is unlikely to affect performance but is an unusual thing to do and makes the code less readable with the potential for "hidden effects"

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I would add that he can multi-thread sum1 and sum2, they're independent.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is intriguing - it got me wondering how much faster it would run with threads.

Here is a threaded implementation that splits the task of calculating the second problem across threads. My laptop only has two cores so I have set the threads to 4.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final long in = 222222222;
    final long target = calcSum(in);
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    final Collection<Future<Integer>> futures = Lists.newLinkedList();
    final int chunk = 100;
    for (long i = in; i > 0; i -= chunk) {
        futures.add(executorService.submit(new Counter(i > chunk ? i - chunk : 0, i, target)));
    }
    long res = 0;
    for (final Future<Integer> f : futures) {
        res += f.get();
    }
    System.out.println(res);
    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
}

public static final class Counter implements Callable<Integer> {

    private final long start;
    private final long end;
    private final long target;

    public Counter(long start, long end, long target) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        int count = 0;
        for (long i = start; i < end; ++i) {
            if (calcSum(i) == target) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}

public static long calcSum(long num) {
    long sum = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        sum += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

It calculates the solution with `222 222 222` as an input in a few seconds.

I optimised the calculation of the `sum` to remove all the `List`s that you were using.

**EDIT**

I added some timing code using `Stopwatch` and tried with and without @Ingo's optimisation using `222222222 * 100` as the input number.

Without the optimisation the code takes 35 seconds. Changing the calc method to:

```
public static long calcSum(long num, final long limit) {
    long sum = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        sum += num % 10;
        if (limit > 0 && sum > limit) {
            break;
        }
        num /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

With the added the optimisation the code takes 28 seconds.

Note this this is a highly non-scientific benchmark as I didn't warm the JIT or run multiple trials (partly because I'm lazy and partly because I'm busy).

**EDIT**

Fiddling with the chunk size gives fairly different results too. With a chunk of 1000 time drops to around 17 seconds.

**EDIT**

If you want to be really fancy you can use a `ForkJoinPool`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final long in = 222222222;
    final long target = calcSum(in);
    final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool();
    final ForkJoinTask<Integer> result = forkJoinPool.submit(new Counter(0, in, target));
    System.out.println(result.get());
    forkJoinPool.shutdown();
    forkJoinPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
}

public static final class Counter extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {

    private static final long THRESHOLD = 1000;
    private final long start;
    private final long end;
    private final long target;

    public Counter(long start, long end, long target) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer compute() {
        if (end - start < 1000) {
            return computeDirectly();
        }
        long mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        final Counter low = new Counter(start, mid, target);
        final Counter high = new Counter(mid, end, target);
        low.fork();
        final int highResult = high.compute();
        final int lowResult = low.join();
        return highResult + lowResult;
    }

    private Integer computeDirectly() {
        int count = 0;
        for (long i = start; i < end; ++i) {
            if (calcSum(i) == target) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}

public static long calcSum(long num) {
    long sum = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        sum += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

On a different (much faster) computer this runs in under a second, as compared to 2.8 seconds for the original approach.

Comment: Can you try to implement the optimization I described, i.e. calcSum with limit?

Comment: Can you try out DivisionCache and ModuloCache from https://github.com/kutschkem/Jayes/tree/master/plugins/org.eclipse.recommenders.jayes/src/org/eclipse/recommenders/jayes/factor/opcache

Answer (score 1):

Observe that you don't need to store the individual digits at all.

Instead, all you're interested in is the actual sum of the digits.

Considering this, a method like

```
static int diagsum(long number)  { ... }
```

would be great. If it is easy enogh, the JIT could inline it, or at least optimize better than your spaghetti code.

Then again, you could benefit from another method that stops computing the digit sum at some limit. Fore example, when you have

```
22222222
```

the sum is 20, and that means that you need not compute any other sum that is greater than 20. For example:

```
45678993
```

Instead, you could just stop after you have the last 3 digits (which you get first by your diision method), because 9+9+3 is 21 and this is alread greater than 20.

===================================================================

Another optimization:

If you have some number:

```
123116
```

it is immediately clear that all unique permutations of those 6 digits have the same digit sum, thus

```
321611, 231611, ... are solutions
```

Then, for any pair of individual digits ab, a transformed number would contain (a+1)(b-1) and (a-1)(b+1) in the same place, as long as a+1, ... are still in the range 0..9. Apply recursively to get even more numbewrs.

You can then turn to numbers with less digits. Obviously, to have the same digit sum, you must combine 2 digits of the original number, if possible, for example

```
5412 => 912, 642, 741, 552, 561, 543
```

etc. 
Apply the same algorithm recursively as above, until no transformations and combinations are possible.

=========

It must be said, though, that above idea would take lots of memory, because one must maintain a Set-like data structure to take care of duplicates. However, for 987_654_321 we get already 39_541_589 results, and probably much more with even greater numbers. Thus it is questionable if the effort to actually do it the combinatorical way is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You spend most of the time checking numbers that are failing the test. However, as Ingo observed, if you have a number ab, then (a-1)(b+1) has the same sum as ab. Instead of checking all numbers, you can generate them:

Lets say our number is 2 222, the sum is 8.
Approach #1: bottom up

We now generate the number starting with the smallest (we pad with zeroes for reading convenience): 0008. The next one is 0017, the next are 0026, 0035, 0044, 0053, 0062, 0071, 0080, 0107 and so on. The problematic part is finding the first number that has this sum.

Approach #2: top down

We start at 2222, the next lower number is 2213, then 2204, 2150, 2141, and so on. Here you don't have the problem that you need to find the lowest number.

I don't have time to write code now, but there should be an algorithm to realize both approaches, that does not involve trying out all numbers.

For a number abc, (a)(b-1)(c+1) is the next lower number, while (a)(b+1)(c-1) is the next higher number. The only interesting/difficult thing is when you need to overflow because b==9 or c==9, or b==0, c==0. The next bigger number if b==9 is (a+1)(9)(c-1) if c>0, and (a)(8)(0) if c==0. Now go make your algorithm, these examples should be enough.